# Which part of circuit becomes electron deficient during charging of an RC circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, capacitance

During the charging of an RC circuit via a battery charge gets accumulated in the capacitor. But according to the conservation of electric charge, some part of the circuit must become electron deficient in order to keep the net charge constant. So my question is which part should become electron-deficient?

P.S Sorry if this question sounds noob but I am just curious to know.

Comment: The plate of the capacitor connected to the - terminal of the battery becomes negatively charged.

Answer (score 2):

Charges do no "accumulate" on a capacitor during charging. The battery does work to remove electrons from one plate and deposit them on the other. The plate from which the electrons are taken then has a net positive charge and the plate to which the electrons are deposited has a net negative charge. So charge is simply moved from one plate to the other. Charge is conserved.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Electrons want to go to positive potential as this decreases their energy. So, the capacitor plate connected to the positive terminal of the battery will be positively charged. This is because the electrons in the capacitor plate will flow toward the positive battery terminal, leaving behind a positive charge on the plate.

The same reasoning can be made for the other capacitor plate connected to the negative terminal. Electrons want to go away from this negative battery terminal and thus flow to the capacitor plate. Hence, the capacitor plate connected to the negative terminal will be negatively charged.